# Javascript make time past faster

Tags: javascript, time

Can I make JavaScript behave as if the time is passing faster?

Specifically for APIs such as `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, etc.

Like pass 10 minutes on JS when 1 second pass on real world.

Comment: A sort of delay of all you do on js?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: javascript was written by Brenden Eich, not H.G. Wells

Comment: @Mr.Bruno a delay would be the opposite of what the OP wants

Comment: @JaromandaX ok I read again and now i can suppose what really he want

Comment: You need your code to act as if 10 minutes has passed when only 1 second has passed.  You don't make Javascript *think* 10 minutes has passed.

Comment: Please give a brief overview of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: (cannot add more answer so adding a comment) what you are probably looking is a library that mocks the clock and timers: https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers

Answer (score 4):

May override setTimeout and setInterval and Date:

```
function TimeMachine(timescale = 0.1, code){   
   const context = Object.create(window); 

   //setTimeout
  const setTimeout = context.setTimeout = function(callb, time){
    window.setTimeout(callb,time*timescale);
  };

  //setInterval
 const setInterval = context.setInterval = function(callb,time){
  window.setInterval(callb,time*timescale);
 };

 //Date TODO:resolve timestrings
 const now = new window.Date().getTime();
 window.setInterval(function(){now+=1/timescale;},1);
 const Date = context.Date = function(){
   this.getTime=function(){
      return now;
   };
 };

   //create Scope with new window
  (function(window){
     eval("("+code+")()");
  })(context);
};
```

Use like this:

```
TimeMachine(0.1,function(){
  //execute in time machines context
  setInterval(function(){alert("10 seconds passed");},10000);//10secs -> 1sec 

  //even this should work:
  window.setTimeout(function(){alert("test")},1000);
});
```

Ive built a time machine :0

References:
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Build-a-Time-Machine-Vortex-Distortion-Spa/

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created a function that when takes two arguments. The first argument is the real world time and second argument is the virtual time it corresponds.

```
$v_time(1000,100); // Maps 1 second of real world as 100ms in virtual world
```

call the function with two arguments to map them and create a virtual time world.

```
$v_time(60000) // returns virtual world time corresponding to real world 60 sec;
```

Now whenever you need the virtual time call the function with the time you want.

```js
$v_time=function (rel_time,vir_time) {
  if(vir_time) $v_time.offset
                  = (Math.min(rel_time,vir_time)
                      /Math.max(rel_time,vir_time));
  return rel_time*$v_time.offset;
}

$v_time(1000,100);  // Maps 1sec of real world as 100ms of virtual world

setTimeout(function(){
             console.log('hello');
          },$v_time(10000)); // 10sec of real world will return 1s of virtual world.
```

To do 10 min real world as 1 seconds of virtual world

```
 $v_time(10*60*1000,1000);
```

now call `$v_time(your_time);`